# Iterate a loop from a parameter value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this `new` method in my controller working fine:

```
  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    2.times do
      @reservation.persons.build
    end
  end
```

I want to have the loop iterate off of a parameter value I will populate, but the loop keeps failing:

```
  def new
    if params[:group_size]
      size = params[:group_size]
    else
      size = 2
    end
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    size.times do
      @reservation.persons.build
    end
  end
```

I am getting the following error (when the parameter is set to 6):

`undefined method 'times' for "6":String`

How do I create this loop to iterate the number that is fed into the `group_size` parameter?

Comment: The error message is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
size = params[:group_size].to_i
```